# What's the furthest a player has run in a single match?

Tags: football

For a while now, football matches have recorded how far each player has run. [This link](https://soccerblade.com/soccer-players-run/#:%7E:text=Jack%20Cork%20(Burnley)%20Total%20distance,of%207.44%20miles%20per%20game.) states that N’golo Kante (Chelsea) ran 306.7 km in 26 matches, for an average of 7.33 miles per game.

How about the record for a single match? What's the known record for the furthest a player has run in a single match?

Comment: [This Reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/soccer/comments/3foaha/comment/ctquwdz/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) claims that Michael Bradley ran 16.9 km during the USA's match against Belgium at the 2014 World Cup, but the link to their source is broken and I haven't found an alternate source, so I'm hesitant to post it as an answer.

Comment: That Reddit comment is just wrong. [Bradley covered a total of 38 km in three group matches](https://www.si.com/soccer/2014/06/28/michael-bradley-usa-world-cup-jurgen-klinsmann), playing 90 minutes every time, and USA were beaten in the next match without e.t. That he somehow did an extra 30% compared to average from three games? Nonsense.

Comment: Of course distance-run does not tell us everything about a player's commitment, or physical stress.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the FIFA World Cup, midfielder **Marcelo Brozovic** of Croatia has held the record since 2018.

His initial record was 16.3 kilometres in the quarterfinal versus Russia, 2018, and was increased to 16.9 kilometres in the round of 16 versus Japan, 2022.

Both games eventually went to kicks from the penalty mark, and Croatia won both from there. The extra time spent on the field  combined with Brozovic's workrate and his positional requirements as a defensive midfielder, explain both the large distances involved and the ability to keep (then improve) the record himself.

This information is reported in various sources, including [Inter Milan's media website](https://sempreinter.com/2022/12/07/inter-midfielder-marcelo-brozovic-breaks-own-record-for-distance-covered-in-a-world-cup-match-in-croatias-win-over-japan-italian-media-highlight/), [the UK's Daily Mail](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/football/article-11528539/Marcelo-Brozovic-Croatias-midfield-maverick-broke-World-Cup-record.html), and a variety of Croatian and worldwide news providers.